# JavaScript - set class if e-mail is wrong

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I've been blinded last 40 minutes trying to find why this isn't working.

So, I have this function to check if e-mail is valid or not

```
checkEmail: function () { // CHECK IF E-MAIL IS WRONG OR NOT
    var check = /^[\w\.\+-]{1,}\@([\da-zA-Z-]{1,}\.){1,}[\da-zA-Z-]{2,6}$/;
    if (!check.test(this.options.email.get('value'))) {
        return false
    }
    return true
},
```

Works well!

Now, I need to set a `error` class to style the input, during validation. For that I used this:

```
var s_email = this.options.email.get('value');
if ((s_email == '') || (s_email == this.options.email_text) || (s_email == 'Give me your e-mail') || (!checkEmail())) { // CHECK AND STYLE E-MAIL INPUT FORM
            this.options.email.set("class", "error")
        } else {
            this.options.email.set("class", "success")
        }
```

But doesn't work, always give me `error` even if a valid email was there.

Comment: What is `this.options.email_text`?

Comment: Maybe create a short little jsFiddle that shows the issue so we can actually debug it?

Comment: @stevuu `email_text: "<?php echo $email_text ?>"` Means `email_text` is the text defined by the Administrator on _backoffice_

Comment: Have you tried other methods of comparing your strings?

Comment: it seems that your condition always evaluates to true. Validate your parameters with the input email address

Comment: @broncoAbierto Other methods like what? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that `checkEmail()` is being called without a context object (value of `this`):

```
if (... || (!checkEmail())) {
```

But, it expects to have one with a particular structure:

```
if (!check.test(this.options.email.get('value'))) {
//              ^^^^
```

The value of `this` is determined when a `function` is called rather than how it's defined. But, you can use [`.call(thisArg)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to specify its value, allowing you to pass along the current context object.

```
if (... || (!checkEmail.call(this))) {
```

Comment: Shouldn't `(!checkEmail())` have resulted in an error that showed in the console?

Comment: @jfriend00 is right, at least according to what is shown in the question. If `checkEmail` is a property on the `this` object, then it should throw. If so, then `this.checkEmail()` would be the solution. If it's a property on `this.options`, then `this.options.checkEmail()` would work as long as `this.options.email.get(...` is changed to `this.email.get(...` in the function.

Comment: Admittedly, had misread the question slightly when I first wrote this. But, since the OP still found it fitting, I'd assume the thrown error is being handled with the `'error'` class being applied then as well.